# How to get values from List

Tags: c#

I have my List with my class which stores two values 
'Position, PlayerType'

```
List<PlayerClass> playerClass = new List<PlayerClass>();
```

and I want to create a spawn.

My code looks like

```
public Vector3 TransformPlayerPosition(PlayerType _myType)
{        
   Vector3 spawnposition = Vector3.zero;

    for (int i = 0; i < playerClass.Count; i++)
    {
        if (playerClass[i].type == _myType)
        {        
            spawnposition = playerClass[i].position;     
        }
    }
    return spawnposition;
  }
```

if playerClass type is like '_myType'
it's works but every time system selects same position ; / i want to create random system to for a specific type like

```
Random.Range(0, playerClass.Count, SPECIFIC TYPE);
```

Comment: This code will always retrieve the last _myType_ present in the list because it loops until the end. However, even if you add a _break_ inside the loop when you find a match then your code will return always the first match. You need to explain better what is a _random position_

Comment: Ok, i will try. My class 'PlayerClass' has two variables 
Vector3 position; and enum with PlayerPrefab, SuperPlayerPrefab
The system(TransformPlayerPosition) should choose a random position from a specific type

Answer (score 4):

Filter your list using LINQ, then grab a random item from the collection:

```
public Vector3 TransformPlayerPosition(PlayerType _myType)
{        
    var filteredPlayers = playerClass.Where(x => type == _myType).ToList();

    if (!filteredPlayers.Any())
        return Vector3.zero;

    var rndPos = rnd.Next(filteredPlayers.Count());

    return filteredPlayers[rndPos].position;
}
```

You'll need to instantiate `rnd` outside of the method somewhere.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

Comment: Yeah, this is better

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry for that mistake hahaha. But still i don't have my new position http://prntscr.com/latl8k

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IEnumerable<EntitySpawner>'

Comment: Now it's works. Thank you so much for helping me out today :)